# OpenGL texture not showing up on some computers, problem with auxDIBImageLoad?

Tags: opengl, winapi

I have a simple openGL GUI that has uses a bmp as a texture.  The problem is on some computers the texture doesn't show up.  But on ones with newer OpenGL drivers it works.  How can I make it more compatible.  I think the problem may be with auxDIBImageLoad.  When I inspect the result, I see the x,y correct, but the data pointer points to memory bank with all zeros.
What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One limitation of older OpenGL implementations is that they do not support non-power-of-two textures. What size is the texture in question ?